# SVG inside <div> always bigger than container

Tags: html, svg, scrollbar

I have a huge SVG file inside a DIV.  I would like to scroll the SVG inside the div by clicking on a A link.

My problem is that I would like my DIV to stay smaller than my SVG document, so I can have active scrollbars.
 Let's say my SVG document's height is 10.000 and 1.100 width, inside a 200px x 100px DIV element. But whatever I do, my DIV element gets as big as the SVG. How can I restrain the size of my div ?

Here is my code:

```
<html>
<title>
YOP
</title>

<head>

<style TYPE="text/css"> 
<!--
  div.header{

background:black;
background-color: #ededed; 
margin-top: 0px;
position: fixed;
top: 0px;
//width:100%;
width:1100px;
height: 500px;
   }

 -->
 </style>


<script type="text/javascript" >        
      var pos = 0;

       function  MyFtion(){
       var elem = document.getElementById('aSVG');      

       pos = pos + 100;
       elem.scrollTop = pos + 100;
       window.scroll(0,   pos);

      }
 </script>
 </head>

 <body bgcolor="white" >

        <div class="header" id="MyDiv2">
        <a href='javascript:MyFtion()'>** Move s**</a> 
        </div>


    <div id="oo"  height="200px" width="100px" style="margin-top:100px;overflow:scroll;" >          
            <object id="aSVG" data="out.svg"  style="margin-top:100px;overflow:hidden;" /> 
    </div>


  </body>
 </html>
```

Note that I tried to add *display:block;* to the style of my OBJECT tag but doesnt work.

Thanks for helping,

Antoine

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sometimes the `height` and `width` HTML attributes don't work well with CSS, so try using the CSS equivalents.

```
#oo{
  height:200px;
  width:100px;
  margin-top:100px;
  overflow:scroll;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot nkorth. It works !!!!!!!! That's really weird it doesnt work the other way round, almost drove me crazy...

Comment: Thanks. I forgot about overflow: scroll

Comment: I didn't the solution. what is the difference here?

Comment: I arrived here dealing with strange "padding" appearing outside my SVG. Specifically setting the h/w fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Define the width & height in the svg:

```
<svg version="1.1" id="baum" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     width="100%"
     xml:space="preserve">
```

into something like this:

```
<svg version="1.1" id="baum" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
width="1000px" height="1000px" viewBox="0 0 200 200"
     xml:space="preserve">
```

I did not try it yet.